# get-childitem variable return empty value when running is powershell script

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

```
$NewestFile = $NULL
$path = "C:\myDirectory"
$NewestFile = Get-ChildItem -filter “FileName*.xlsx” -recurse -path $path |
    Sort LastWriteTime -Descending |
    Select -First 1
Write-Host " NewestFile" $NewestFile
```

I have several files with nearly the same name and I want to select the newest file for processing.  When I run this on the command line it works fine but the same code will not run from a powershell script.

Comment: What's the error or unexpected output?

Answer (score 0):

Looks good except the `Write-Host`. If you want a property of the `$NewestFile` object such as full path or some such, use `$NewestFile.FullName`